# Built in camera stop working after multiple reload of a webpage

Tags: webcam, camera

As the topic say my camera stop working after multiple reload of a web page using Firefox.
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 up to date.
I am a web developer and was working with p5js trying to play with my built-in camera streaming and it suddenly stopped working. I tryed to load Cheese but it throw me an error that it couldn't access my camera, same for framatalk or whatever camera related software. Even after rebooting my laptop the camera still doesn't show up.

The only thing related to my problem I found was [this page](https://digitizor.com/how-to-reload-ubuntu-linux-laptop-webcam-fix-without-restart/) but as I am still a beginner on Ubuntu I don't want to throw some random command without knowing what it does.

Does anyone have a clue on how to deal with/fix this issue?

Comment: Try a live session. If the problem is the same then you have to conclude it's hardware.

Comment: I restart my computer this morning and the camera is working good.... So it seams to be a software problem, probably relative something inside the OS. How can I debug things relative to camera?

Comment: Also, could someone explain those two line of code :
`sudo rmmod uvcvideo`
`sudo modprobe uvcvideo`
That's the only things I found and would like to understand them a bit. It could be a first step to find a good resolution to y problem

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out why my camera was stuck.
As I was trying to understand what's wrong with my camera, I opened up multiple window with camera working as the same.
It seams that the webcam can only be focused on one window / tool. So if it's dedicate to one web browser window it can't be opened with Cheers for exemple or event another window.

As simple as that...

Thank you guys for your answers and for your time.

Cheers!